# Association on different column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models:

`rails generate model RoomType code:string description:text`

```
class RoomType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms
end
```

`rails generate model room name:string code:string`

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room_type, foreign_key: "code"
end
```

I want to reference `Room` with `RoomType` on `code` and not `room_type_id`.

So I do `@room.room_type.description` in my `rooms/show.html.erb` and I get `undefined method description for nil:NilClass`

`RoomType` will only contain three codes i.e. AAA, BBB, CCC

Comment: And it should have worked. What was the problem about it?

Comment: Can you post rooms/show.html.erb?

Comment: Also, `code` is defined as string, which I don't think is appropriate for a foreign key column.

Comment: Use `@room.room_type.try(:description)` to see if the record actually has a room_type

Comment: The @room does't have the room_type that is the problem, the association is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Don't create a class called "Type". Change this name, maybe "Kind", I don't know.

Check this list [Reserved words in rails](http://bparanj.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/reserved-words-in-rails.html)

Comment: Actually the real class name is different. But good point. I updated the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changed it to best practice (it is not best practice to use foreign key as string):

`rails g migration add_room_type_id_to_rooms room_type_id:integer`

```
class RoomType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room_type
end
```